# Is there an equivalent for mysql DATE() function in mongodb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I want something like this in mongodb

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-10-12' AND '2017-10-12'
```

**date** field stores datetime and its type is ISODATE. how can i do this?

Comment: https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-query-mongodb-by-date-or-isodate/

Comment: and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112179/date-range-query-for-past-24-hour-in-mongo-shell

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: The second article doesn't help? How come? What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MongoDB Query-**

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
date:{
    $gte:ISODate(<FromDate>),
    $lte:ISODate(<ToDate>)}
});
```

**Example-**

```
db.getCollection('users').find({
date:{
    $gte:ISODate("2016-10-12T10:08:16.111Z"),
    $lte:ISODate("2017-10-12T10:08:16.111Z")}
});
```

Hope this will help you!